# SQL RANK() over PARTITION on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rank

I have two tables RSLTS and CONTACTS:

**RSLTS**

```
 QRY_ID  |  RES_ID  |  SCORE
-----------------------------
   A     |    1     |    15
   A     |    2     |    32
   A     |    3     |    29
   C     |    7     |    61
   C     |    9     |    30
```

**CONTACTS**

```
 C_ID  |  QRY_ID  |  RES_ID
----------------------------
  1    |    A     |    2
  2    |    A     |    1
  3    |    C     |    9
```

I'm trying to create a report that would show, for each **CONTACT** record (`C_ID`), the `RANK()` of `RES_ID` (by `SCORE`) in the **RSLTS** table within its group (`QRY_ID`). Using the data above, it would look like this:

```
 C_ID  |  QRY_ID  |  RES_ID  |  SCORE  |  Rank
-----------------------------------------------
  1    |    A     |    2     |    32   |   1
  2    |    A     |    1     |    15   |   3
  3    |    C     |    9     |    30   |   2
```

So far, I tried this but it returns Rank = 1 for the last row (and rank = 2 for the second which is also wrong)

```
SELECT
    C.*
    ,R.SCORE
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY R.QRY_ID ORDER BY R.SCORE DESC)
FROM CONTACTS C LEFT JOIN RSLTS R
ON C.RES_ID = R.RES_ID
AND C.QRY_ID = R.QRY_ID
```

UPDATE: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ef2f/1)

Comment: Are you sure?  [I get your expected results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da810/1).  Also, what's up with all the abbreviations?  And might you really mean `DENSE_RANK()` (which will close 'gaps' between rankings)?

Comment: Thanks for the SQLFiddle. The data I have here locally showed something different. I updated the data in this SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ef2f/1) where the last record should show rank = 2 instead of 1 since 61 > 30

Comment: At the moment your results are equivalent to `RANK() OVER(ORDER BY r.score DESC)`.... Are you sure you need to partition (you don't have any repetitions in your ranking).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the rank doesn't depend at all from the contacts

**RANKED_RSLTS**

```
 QRY_ID  |  RES_ID  |  SCORE |  RANK
-------------------------------------
   A     |    1     |    15  |   3
   A     |    2     |    32  |   1
   A     |    3     |    29  |   2
   C     |    7     |    61  |   1
   C     |    9     |    30  |   2
```

Thus :

```
SELECT
    C.*
    ,R.SCORE
    ,MYRANK
FROM CONTACTS C LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  *,
 MYRANK = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY QRY_ID ORDER BY SCORE DESC)
  FROM RSLTS)  R
ON C.RES_ID = R.RES_ID
AND C.QRY_ID = R.QRY_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.C_ID,a.QRY_ID,a.RES_ID,b.SCORE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SCORE DESC) AS [RANK]
FROM CONTACTS a JOIN RSLTS b ON a.QRY_ID=b.QRY_ID AND a.RES_ID=b.RES_ID
ORDER BY a.C_ID
```

Comment: Please do not provide a code-only answers, but explain why/how the solution is working. Also please edit your code to show correctly.

Comment: Sure,will do next time.Just a newbie and try to answer the question.Thanks for your advise.

Comment: You can still edit your post and add an explanation!