# Pick first result from multiple matches when using WHERE

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a "problem" when performing an area search based on zip codes, longitudes and latitudues with MySQL. But there exist **duplicate zip codes** within a country.

I'm currently performing a first query, to check for multiple results and pick the first one (as they only have a very small difference in distance). But I want to do it in one query.

Is there a way, to **ignore multiple matches when using WHERE** or simply **pick the first one**.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    dest.zc_zip,
    dest.zc_location_name,
    ACOS(
         SIN(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
         + COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(dest.zc_lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(src.zc_lon) - RADIANS(dest.zc_lon))
    ) * 6380 AS distance
FROM zip_coordinates dest
CROSS JOIN zip_coordinates src
CROSS JOIN users u
WHERE src.zc_id = 2 /* searching for id */
AND u.zip = dest.zc_zip
AND u.city = dest.zc_location_name
HAVING distance < 100
ORDER BY distance;
```

Here I want to change `src.zc_id = 2` to something like `src.zc_zip = XXXX`

**Edit:**

I also created a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fb6a/3

Comment: If I understand correctly, can't you just put a `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query? In other words, `... ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1`.

Comment: I can't try now, but seems rank() can be useful. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962950/sql-rank-over-partition-on-joined-tables)

Comment: @EdGibbs i want to search all users within a radius, based on a zip code, but want get all users within that radius. if there are more results for `WHERE src_zc_zip = XXX`, it should simply pick the first, to have only one "base zip code". so limit is not my choice.
@bellabax thanks, i'll look into rank()

Comment: Got it - seeing your query I figured you knew about `LIMIT` but you never know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question properly, you want to replace the

`WHERE src.zc_id = 2 /* searching for id */`

line with something like:

```
WHERE src.zc_id = (SELECT ... FROM zip_coordinates where ...)
```

And you want the result of the WHERE clause to be a single value. In that case you can just use the MAX function. Something like:

```
WHERE src.zc_id = (SELECT MAX(zc_id) FROM zip_coordinates where ...)
```

It would be helpful if you provide more information about the query you are running before this SELECT query to pick one of the results.

Comment: that's it. thank you! i used `WHERE src.zc_id = (SELECT MAX(zc_id) FROM zip_coordinates WHERE zc_zip = XXXXX)` .. what do you think about performance of this query when zip_coordinates has about 18000 entries?

Comment: That depends on how you select the src.zc_id. I am not a pro in performance tuning but if the inner subquery in the WHERE clause refers to a column in the outer query then the subquery is repeated for each row of the outer query's resultset and hence it is not that efficient.

Comment: thanks for your reply! in this case it's not repeated for each row, right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5effb6/1 .. or would you use a something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5effb6/2

Comment: As far as I know, since your subquery is not correlated to the outer query, it will only be executed once and the result will be cached. So in theory both methods should perform the same.